# how to tag an image on NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have an UIImageview on the centre of my app and it is running sequentially on all my images (16 images ).
I need to "tag" the image that appeared on UIImageview so then I can create a condition to run another code .

```
//here is my code 


pics = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:

        [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"11.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"12.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"13.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"14.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"15.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"16.png"],
        nil];


 self.centreImage.animationImages = pics;

self.centreImage.animationDuration = 20.0;
self.centreImage.animationRepeatCount = INFINITY;
[self.centreImage startAnimating];

// here is when the condition has to  "detect the image/tag"    
if (centreImage.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]);

//run this code
```

Any help will much appreciated
Thank you

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't be using == when comparing objects; isEqual: is typically the way to go. Not entirely helpful here (excepting that +imageNamed: might create a new instance), but you'll want to know this for down the road.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `NSObject` for each `UIImage`. And inside `NSObject` you can *create all image attributes-properties and tags etc*. After that you will create an `NSArray` in your `UIViewController` and add these `NSObject` to `NSArray`.

Comment: You don't need an `NSObject`. `UIView` has a `tag` property and `UIImageView` is a subclass of `UIView` so it has the `tag` property too.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes for now he doesn't need nsobject, like you say it has own tag property. But i think he will eventually need nsobject :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (centreImage.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]);
```

Fails because `imageNamed:` is likely to return a new image.

I'd recommend attempting to to pull the image index:

```
NSUInteger imageIndex = [pics indexOfObject:centreImage.image];
```

Here, `0` would be your first image, `1` your second, etc.

A refinement of this would be to capture the index of the image when you switch to a new one.

A yet further refinement would be to avoid loading all images into your array and simply load images as needed. Here you would track the numerical file name of the image and construct the file name as needed.